# Cratedb custom sorting

Tags: cratedb

For example, we have elements like

```
12345678

23487653

12475805

23382349
```

when we search for `234` I want to see order as

```
23487653

12345678

23382349
```

For searching, I am using ngram analyzer, but not able to figure out how to do the sorting.I tried sorting on _score, but _score is same for many values

Postgresql has `position` function, that is currently not supported in cratedb.